# Simple JOpenID string declaration

Tags: jopenid

I am new to programming and JOpenID, what is a simple code example? I have heard that it is similar to Java, even though I do not know Java. My programmer friends recommended JOpenID and they say you need to learn declarations first.

Comment: this may be the wrong place for you, check resources like codecademy for programming experience

Comment: And khan Academy, they are great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend learning Java first, but a simple code example for a String declaration would be this:

```
private static final String ATTR_MAC = "string1"; 

private static final String ATTR_ALIAS = "string2";
```